# validata the image and word issue

Tags: javascript, html

**Hello I need help with my java-script code. I have multiple images set on my webpage where you click on it, it plays a sound of the image. I'm try to validate the word that generate in textbox with the image. For example, if wordbox generate the word "House". when user click on House image it show display "Good Job" message but if user select some other image it display"sorry wrong answer" message. How can I do that ? Below is my source code for html and js.  **

```js
var NumberOfWords = 8

var words = new BuildArray(NumberOfWords)

// Use the following variables to 
// define your random words:
words[1] = "Car"
words[2] = "House"
words[3] = "Farm"
words[4] = "Train"
words[5] = "Pizza"
words[6] = "Television"
words[7] = "Phone"
words[8] = "Plane"


function BuildArray(size) {
    this.length = size
    for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        this[i] = null
    }
    return this
}

function PickRandomWord(frm) {
    // Generate a random number between 1 and NumberOfWords
    var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords)

    // Display the word inside the text box
    frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd]
}
```

```css
body.body-img {
    background: url('../images/pen&pencil.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.h1-title h1 {
    background-color: dimgray;
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #000, 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    font-size:50px
}







#wordbox {
    /*opacity: 0;*/
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color:black;
    transition: 1s linear;
}

#button {
    background: #0b7fba;
    border: 2;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 1em ;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css"/>
    <script src="../../javascript/beginner.js"></script>
    <title>Beignner Lesson</title>
</head>
    
    
<body class="body-img">
<div class="h1-title">
<h1>Welcome to Beignner Level</h1>

 <p>Random word generator and then click on the image base on that word.</p>
</div>

<br />
<br />

<h2>Word Display</h2>

<form NAME="WordForm">  
<input type=text name="WordBox" id="wordbox"><BR>
<input type=button value="Generate Word" onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm);" id="button">
</form>


<div class="images">
    <audio id="audio" src="../../sounds/car.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="../../images/lesson/toy-car.png" id="ToyCar" onclick="document.getElementById('audio').play(); return false;" height="200" width="300" />  
    

    <audio id="audio1" src="../../sounds/train.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="../../images/lesson/train.png" onclick="document.getElementById('audio1').play(); return false;" height="200" width="300"  />
    
    <audio id="audio2" src="../../sounds/house.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="../../images/lesson/house.png" onclick="document.getElementById('audio2').play(); return false;" height="200" width="300"  />
    
    <audio id="audio3" src="../../sounds/television.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="../../images/lesson/tv.png" onclick="document.getElementById('audio3').play(); return false;" height="200" width="300"  />

 <br /> <br /> <br />

    <audio id="audio4" src="../../sounds/farm.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="../../images/lesson/farm.png" onclick="document.getElementById('audio4').play(); return false;" height="200" width="300"  />
   
    <audio id="audio5" src="../../sounds/phone.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="../../images/lesson/phone.png" onclick="document.getElementById('audio5').play(); return false;" height="200" width="300" />
   
    <audio id="audio6" src="../../sounds/plane.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="../../images/lesson/plane.png" onclick="document.getElementById('audio6').play(); return false;" height="200" width="300" />
   
    <audio id="audio7" src="../../sounds/pizza.mp3"></audio>
    <img src="../../images/lesson/pizza.png" onclick="document.getElementById('audio7').play(); return false;" height="200" width="300" />
 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want to play 2 different sounds based on user selection - One for the right answer and other for incorrect.

Approach:

Whenever a user clicks on the image, you can check if this is a correct selection and then you can play the audio from javascript which is fairly simple.

```
var audio = new Audio('your_audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();
```